# Shim to fix over-trimmed door

Tags: doors, trim, shim

I had a handyman come by and trim a few of my interior doors because they were sticking from expansion from the humidity.

It turns out, one of the door jams is uneven, so now there is a bigger gap on one side of the top of the door that lets light through at night.

I have some weather stripping, but the gap is too big, and I would prefer to not have weather stripping there, since it gives some resistance when latching the door.

I’m not particularly handy, but I was thinking I can wood-glue a shim to the top of the door, then plane it down a bit and paint.

Does this seem like a reasonable way to go about it?

Comment: Why not just plane down the offending part of the door?

Comment: The door was already trimmed too much on top. I want to reduce the gap that’s there now by filling it with something.